# Ant: No such file or directory

Tags: java, linux, ant, exec

I need to write ant script to execute one file in linux but prior to execution of file i need to execute setup file.

in putty i used to something like ". ./setup" and then "./executeme"

In same way i have written ant script as

```
    <exec dir="${dir}" executable="/bin/sh">
        <arg value=". ./setup"/>
        <arg value="./executeme"/>
    </exec>
```

But it gives error as "/bin/sh: . ./setup: No such file or directory".

Also can someone explain me the difference between execution of "./setup" and ". ./setup "??

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run the command sequence you use in an interactive session by creating a single-line script, and passing it to `sh` using `-c` like this:

```
<exec dir="${dir}" executable="/bin/sh">
    <arg value="-c"/>
    <arg value=". ./setup; ./executeme"/>
</exec>
```

You need to pass the two commands as one `arg`, otherwise they are treated differently: the first one becomes the 'script' and the next becomes the first argument for that script.  Or, if you like, the above is equivalent to running

```
sh -c ". ./setup; ./executeme"
```

whereas with separate `arg` elements, you are running

```
sh -c ". ./setup" ./executeme
```

That probably won't appear to fail, unless `setup` does something its argument list, but it won't run `executeme`.

Answer (score 0):

```
value="./setup"
```

without `.` at the beginning.

Comment: ahhh...I tried that one but executeme doesnt work.. Do you know what is the difference between execution of "./setup" and ". ./setup "??

Comment: yes, I know. `. ./setup` means execute `./setup` in the current shell. In your case that has no sense because you start a new shell anyway. But if you want `. ./setup` you need to use key `-c`: `sh -c '. ./setup'`. so it would be correct. But I would repeat: you need no `.` (`source`) command in this case.

Comment: I have one doubt, i tried it as"<arg value="./setup"/>
   <arg value="./executeme"/>" and it doesnt give any error but nothing executed. So my doubt is that can we able to give multiple argument value to executable?